# Window.open to open an URL with silent login

Tags: javascript

I have a scenario, where when i click on a button in javascript ,it has to open an application . This application has login details(username and password).

I am using window.open to open an url.

Can you please let me know how to pass credentials details in window.open but it has to be encrypted. This credential should be added to application .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post some code showing how much you have done...??

Comment: Initially, i will be checking for browser versions and then , window.open("myApplication.com") . This myApplication.com asks for username and password.  Now., i should pass the credential details that is required by myApplication.com when i am opening the window

Comment: What does this question have to do with [tag:typescript]?

Comment: I am currently using javascript..

Answer (score 0):

One thing what you can do, store the required data in local storage and then when open the pop up, use the same local storage data. You can store user name, passwords in form of cookies also.